# Angular dynamic validation only when formControl is invalid

Tags: angular, form-control, formgroups

I want the formControl to have a `updateOn: 'change'` behavior, but only once the user has ended typing and it turns to be invalid.

This is how my formGroup looks like:

```js
  controlValidation = '^((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]' + '{1,63}(?<!-)\\.)' + '+[A-Za-z]{2,3}';

  campaignForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group(
    { control: [null, Validators.pattern(this.controlValidation)]},
    { updateOn: 'blur' }
  );
```

And the template looks something like this

```html
 <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" formControlName="advertiserDomain" />
   <div *ngIf="campaignForm.get('control').invalid">
      Error message that should only display reactivly BUT only once the user finished writing for the first time
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to show the error message only when the user finishes typing into the input control?

Comment: you can use update on blur but also validate the empty input as a valid value

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand the exact meaning of what you are asking but I'll try answer:

Basically the `formGroup` have no possibilities to know if user starts or ends typing its word or sentence, this is why `change` is triggered on every changes. Still you could do a hack, considering many characters are typed in a row, you could add a `setTimeout` that is cancelled when a key is pressed before a certain delay (let say 1 second) and when the delay reaches 1 second use  the method `updateValueAndValidity()` to manually trigger the validity check of your form.

the below code have not been tested but that's the main idea.

your html:

```
<input type="text" (input)="keyPress()" formControlName="advertiserDomain" />
```

your ts:

```
timeout;

keyPress(){

  clearTimeout(this.timeout);

  this.timeout = setTimeout( _ => {
     this.campaignForm.updateValueAndValidity();
  }, 1000);
}
```